# prior life what hope can we have related to our present life?

Tags: karma, daily-life

If our present existence is the result of something we could not control (from a prior life), what hope can we have related to our present situation in this life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our present 'existence' (state of mind) does not have to be related to a prior life. The scriptures explain having such a view results in having no hope & leaves one stuck in inaction.

> *When one falls back on what was done in the past as being essential, monks, there is no desire, no effort [at the thought], 'This should be
>   done. This shouldn't be done.' When one can't pin down as a truth or
>   reality what should & shouldn't be done, one dwells bewildered &
>   unprotected. One cannot righteously refer to oneself as a
>   contemplative. This was my first righteous refutation of those
>   brahmans & contemplatives who hold to such teachings, such views.*
>
> [Tittha Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.061.than.html)

Comment: Yes, that's a good attitude but past life karma was the reason a person was born, "prarabdha" karma. It's what caused a person to take another life and it must be settled. But all life is not "past karma" playing out. There are 4 flavors of karma in play. Sometimes knowing what debt we have brings awareness of how to live and settle things and avoid future karma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43554/discussion-between-dhammadhatu-and-alex-s).